# PDO query returns blank records when none should be returned

Tags: php, database, pdo

While loading a HTML page I also do database queries to fill several 'select' drop downs.  I found that 1 query returns 23 blank records (at least that is what it appears to do) and adds 23 blank 'options' to the drop down.  Since the table for this query (#2) does not exist yet I expect no records to be returned by the query and no records be added to the drop down.  23 records happens to be the same number of records returned by query #1.  No errors are reported in the PHP error log, other than invalid index messages about the column names (2 of them).

I wrote the Database class many years ago when I was learning PHP.  I have looked over the class code but I don't see anything wrong.  I create the database object at the top of the page and use that 1 object for all queries.

I have posted both queries and all class functions used.  Since I don't see the problem I'm hoping someone can.

Thank you for any and all help,

Charles

Query 1, works as expected:

```
<div class="container" title="Please select your name suffix.">
 <label for="suffix">Suffix:</label><br>
 <select id="suffix" name="suffix" onchange="">
  <option value="0"<?php if(isset($_POST["suffix"]) && (($_POST["suffix"] == "0") || ($_POST["suffix"] == "1"))) echo(' selected="selected"');?>>&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="1"><?php echo("S" == "P" ? "Add New/Edit Prefix" : "Add New/Edit Suffix");?></option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `abbrev`, `description` FROM `{$pdo->db_name}`.`name_pre-suf` WHERE `type` = :type ORDER BY `abbrev` ASC;";
$pdo->query($sql);
$pdo->bind(":type", str_ToUpper("S"));
$results = $pdo->resultSet();
if($pdo->rowCount())
{
 foreach($results as $row)
 {
  echo("      <option value=\"" . SafeDisplay($row["id"]) . "\"");
  if(isset($_POST["suffix"]))
  {
   if(SafeDisplay($row["id"]) == SafeDisplay($_POST["suffix"]))
   {
    echo(" selected=\"selected\"");
   } // Closing brace for if(SafeDisplay($row["id"]) == SafeDisplay($_POST["suffix"]))
  } // Closing brace for if(isset($_POST["suffix"]))
  echo(">" . SafeDisplay($row["abbrev"]) . " - " . SafeDisplay($row["description"]) . "</option>" . PHP_EOL);
 } // Closing brace for foreach($results as $row)
} // Closing brace for if($pdo->rowCount())
?>
 </select>
 <span id="cefiform_suffix_errorloc" class="error"><?php if(isset($validator) && array_key_exists('suffix', $validator->errors)) echo(implode('<br>', $validator->errors['suffix']));?></span>
</div>
```

Query 2, should not work because the table 'countries' does not exist yet.  I expect no records to be added.  However, 23 records are returned and 23 blank 'options' are added.  23 happens to be the number of records retured by query 1.

```
<div class="container" title="Please select your country.">
 <label for="ctry">Country:</label><br>
 <select id="ctry" name="ctry">
  <option value="0"<?php if(isset($_POST["ctry"]) && (($_POST["ctry"] == "0") || ($_POST["ctry"] == "1"))) echo(' selected="selected"');?>>&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="1">Add New/Edit Country</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `alpha2_id`, `common_name` FROM `{$pdo->db_name}`.`countries` ORDER BY `common_name` ASC;";
$pdo->query($sql);
$results = $pdo->resultSet();
if($pdo->rowCount())
{
 foreach($results as $row)
 {
  echo("      <option value=\"" . SafeDisplay($row["alpha2_id"]) . "\"");
  if(isset($_POST["ctry"]))
  {
   if(SafeDisplay($row["alpha2_id"]) == SafeDisplay($_POST["ctry"]))
   {
    echo(" selected=\"selected\"");
   } // Closing brace for if(SafeDisplay($row["alpha2_id"]) == SafeDisplay($_POST['ctry']))
  } // Closing brace for if(isset($_POST['ctry']))
  echo(">" . SafeDisplay($row["common_name"]) . "</option>" . PHP_EOL);
 } // Closing brace for foreach($results as $row)
} // Closing brace for if($pdo->rowCount())
?>
 </select>
 <span id="cefiform_ctry_errorloc" class="error"><?php if(isset($validator) && array_key_exists('ctry', $validator->errors)) echo(implode('<br>', $validator->errors['ctry']));?></span>
</div>

class Database
{
 // Set database handler and database name variables
 private $pdo;
 public $db_name;

 // Set errors variable
 public $errors = array();

 public function bind($param, $value = null, $type = null)
 {
  if(is_array($param) && is_null($value) && is_null($type))
  {
   foreach($param as $key => $value)
   {
    $this->bind($key, $value);
   } // Closing brace for foreach($param as $key => $value)
  } // Closing brace for if(is_array($param) && is_null($value) && is_null($type))
  else
  {
   if(is_null($type))
   {
    switch(true)
    {
     case is_int($value):
      $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
      break;
     case is_bool($value):
      $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
      break;
     case is_null($value):
      $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
      break;
     default:
      $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      break;
    }
   }
   $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
  } // Closing brace for if(is_array($param) && is_null($value) && is_null($type)) else
 }

 public function query($query)
 {
  try
  {
   $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   $this->addError("pdo", $e->getMessage());
  }
 }

 public function resultSet()
 {
  $this->execute();
  return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }

 public function rowCount()
 {
  return $this->stmt->rowCount();
 }
}
```

Comment: What does `Database::addError()` do? When you get an error in the query, you just call that, but don't stop the script.

Comment: @Barmar, it just adds an error message to the $errors variable.  With the try/catch I thought no return or anything was needed.

Comment: `try/catch` prevents the error from stopping the program. It adds the message to the variable, then continues as if everything was OK. But it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar, Ok I'm lost.  If I add 'return null' to the error part of the query function nothing changes.  What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Database` class needs to clear `$this->stmt` if the call to `prepare()` fails.

```
 public function query($query)
 {
  try
  {
   $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   $this->addError("pdo", $e->getMessage());
   $this->stmt = null;
  }
```

And all the other methods that use `$this->stmt` need to check if it's null first. For example:

```
 public function resultSet()
 {
  if (!$this->stmt) {
    return [];
  }
  $this->execute();
  return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
```

Comment: While you were writing this answer I came up with a fix.  You and I are on the same page except, I wrapped the other functions with '!is_null()' instead.  Do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: That means you have to fix every caller instead of just hiding it in the class.

Comment: That means I should do it your way.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: One problem, the parser complained about the '[' in the return statement.  So, instead of 'return []' I used 'return array()'.  Was that OK?

Comment: You must be using an ancient version of PHP. `[]` syntax was added in 5.4. `array()` is fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP v5.3.? because of client requirements.